# DexNav different crown colors

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've  noticed that sometimes when I catch all the Pokémon  on a route I get a gold crown on my DexNav and sometimes  I get a bronze. Both say I caught all the  Pokémon in the area.

What is the difference between the two and are there any others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A crown emblem may appear in the upper right of the DexNav, to indicate the player's progress.

- **Platinum**: all of the wild Pokémon in the area are in the player's Pokédex;
- **Gold**: the only missing Pokémon are foreign species unlocked by the defeat of Groudon/Kyogre;
- **Silver**: the player is missing Pokémon from only one of the other encounter methods (tall grass, fishing and surfing);
- **Bronze**: the player is missing Pokémon from two of the other encounter methods;
- No crown otherwise.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DexNav#Mark_of_completion).